# How to keep reference to object across tabs?

Tags: c#, android, tabs, xamarin.android, fragment-tab-host

I currently have issues with implementing a FragmentTabHost with shared data between its tabs.

I have the fragment containing the FragmentTabHost set up like this:

```
public class TTTabContainerFragment: Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment{
  TTDataSet SharedData;

  //OnCreate and initialization...

 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
      FragmentHost = new FragmentTabHost(Activity);
      FragmentHost.Setup(Activity, ChildFragmentManager);
      FragmentHost.AddTab(FragmentHost.NewTabSpec("tab1").SetIndicator(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.BOOKHOUR_ITEM_BOOKING)), new TTBookHourFragment().Class, TTDataSets.CreateArgumentBundle(SharedData));
      FragmentHost.AddTab(FragmentHost.NewTabSpec("tab2").SetIndicator(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.BOOKHOUR_ITEM_INFO)), new TTBookHourInfoFragment().Class, TTDataSets.CreateArgumentBundle(SharedData));
      FragmentHost.AddTab(FragmentHost.NewTabSpec("tab3").SetIndicator(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.BOOKHOUR_ITEM_EXPENSES)), new TTBookHourExpenseDialog().Class, TTDataSets.CreateArgumentBundle(SharedData));
      return FragmentHost;
 }

 public override void OnDestroyView()
 {
       base.OnDestroyView();
       FragmentHost = null;
 }
```

Each of these tabs needs to have access to and should be able to manipulate the data in the SharedData dataset. While I can "send the data" to the tab fragments by serializing/parceling the SharedData set into a bundle, the references to the original DataSet in the container fragment are lost and a new object is created in the tab fragments. Therefore the data manipulations aren't shared between the tabs.

Is there any way to share the data between the 3 tabs to make sure manipulations to the data persists between them? Preferrably without resorting to static variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can add supportive method in activity. Fragments are always shown in activity. SO using activity you can share data what you want. Hope fragment loaded in same activity.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
 int a;
   void setData(int a){
   this.a=a
   }

   int getData(){
    return a;
   }


}


class MyFragment extends Fragent{

  void onViewCreated{
    ((MyActivity)getActivity()).getData(); //Access data
  }
}
```

Other way is just declare class and keep your data to static so it will accesible to all components.

Or you can define data in application class that will accesible from application context (ie from each component of android)